# Switching between Branches in SVN and Git

Tags: git, svn, version-control, branching-and-merging

In SVN (or Git), suppose you are in a working copy directory which has been created by checking out branch A.  Now, I need to work and commit to branch B.

In SVN, I can use the `svn switch B` and in Git, I can use `git checkout B` in order to switch to the branch B.

However, I always have fear of this switching operation; so, I end up creating a new working copy and when I need to work on many branches, I end up with many obsolete working directories.

My question is if the switching the same working copy between different branches is totally safe or not.  Do SVN or Git keep any of the files which belong to the other branch, or they really clean up and switch to the new branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A switch between branches is the safe operation. 
I see only one concern: if you have a lot of modified files in your working copy.
You may be require to perform a merge or your modified files will be removed.
So, if you have a lot of modified files it is better to checkout a new brunch in a new folder.

Comment: there is `git stash` for local modifications

Comment: Another concern might arise if you are in Windows and a file has a lock on it but overall Michael is correct

Comment: IMHO, git stash is better to use when you want to provide a hot fix on the same brunch.

Comment: @Michael: So, assuming that I commit all the changes in the existing branch so that I don't really need a local working copy of it anymore, and switching to the new branch is totally safe.  I mean I wouldn't care if the files from the existing branch are removed since I have already committed them.

Comment: Correct, when you commit a working copy is equal to a branch and you can safely perform switch.

Comment: Careful, any non-tracked files will be left out of this. Just make sure you know which files are under version control, and which aren't. The easiest split is between hand-made files and generated ones, I'd stick to that as much as possible.